# Do "square-rootable" sequences of integers have square-rootable suffixes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, radicals

I'm interested in finite sequences of positive integers $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ such that $$
\sqrt{(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)} := \sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2 + \cdots + \stackrel{\vdots}{\sqrt{a_n}}}}
$$ is an integer. Call such a sequence "square-rootable".

If is a sequence is square-rootable, does that imply all of its suffixes are too? That is, must $\sqrt{(a_i, a_{i+1}, \dots a_n)}$ also be an integer for all $1 \leq i \leq n$? If not, what is a counter-example?

Comment: The square root of a non-integer is not an integer, and the sum of an integer and a non-integer is not an integer, so any non-integer appearing at any stage would prevent the the overall result from being an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sqrt{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}\in\mathbb{N}$ then $$\sqrt{(a_i,\ldots,a_n)}=(\ldots((\sqrt{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}^2-a_1)^2-a_2)^2-\ldots)^2-a_{i-1}\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: Thanks! Clearer in hindsight!

Comment: You only need the case $i=2,$ giving you much clearer notation. The rest follows by induction.